# Lazarus Delphi Pasca Поиск строки в txt файле и вывод в Memo

Tags: delphi, pascal, lazarus, turbopascal

Делаю проект-справочник OBD2 кодов, необходимо в txt файлах найти строку по номеру кода типа "Pyxxx" где "P" это буквы P,B,C,U; "y" это это число от 0 до 3 включительно; а "xxx" это как буквы так и цифры. Файл где искать, пользователь выбирает в combobox1 и одновременно букву которая записана и изменяется в параметре label1.caption; Числа от 0 до 3 записаны в параметре combobox2.ItemIndex и их может выбрать пользователь (В некоторых файлах число фиксированное); последние 3 числа/буквы пользователь вводит в edit1.text. Я хотел выводить строку в Memo через Tstring.String но проблема в том что данный оператор принимает только integer (номер строки в файле) но не текст.

Как сделать так чтобы в файлах искались строки по совмещенному параметру "label1.caption+combobox2.ItemIndex+edit1.text"?

Answer (score 0):

s - строка, в которой ищем, полученная через Readln или из StringList. Добавил, как её получить из списка

```
subs := label1.caption+combobox2.Text+edit1.text;
for i:= 0 to StrList.Length - 1 do begin
   s := StrList[i];
   if Pos(subs, s) > 0 then
      Memo1.Lines.Add(s);
end;
```

Что такое `данный оператор` - непонятно.

Comment: попробовал данный способ, не работает возможно из-за того что у меня в есть текст в параметре Memo2.lines.Text:='Значение кода'; 
Можно ли как это вывести через Memo2.Lines.Text:=Tstring.Strings[]?

Comment: Этот способ работает, а слова ваши непонятны

Comment: В TurboVision был TStringList

Comment: @Viktor Tomilov Точно, я уже и забыл.